# Select attributes of WFS FeatureTypes

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, getfeature

I want to select polygons in WFS FeatureTypes (OpenLayers). I used the code of this example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeature-wfs.html . Then, when I select a polygon in my the layer nothing is selected, I don't no why. Could you help me please.

Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="OpenLayers/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<title>WFS: GetFeature Example (GeoServer)</title>
<script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, layer, select, hover, control;
    function init(){
        //OpenLayers.ProxyHost= "";
        //OpenLayers.ProxyHost= "proxy.cgi?url=";
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
            controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()
            ]
        });
        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "States WMS/WFS",
            "http://v2.suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/ows",
            {layers: 'usa:states', format: 'image/gif'}
        );
        select = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selection", {styleMap: 
            new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["select"])
        });
        hover = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Hover");
        map.addLayers([layer, hover, select]);

        control = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
            protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(layer),
            box: true,
            hover: true,
            multipleKey: "shiftKey",
            toggleKey: "ctrlKey"
        });
        control.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e) {
            select.addFeatures([e.feature]);
            alert("yes");
        });
        control.events.register("featureunselected", this, function(e) {
            select.removeFeatures([e.feature]);
        });
        control.events.register("hoverfeature", this, function(e) {
            hover.addFeatures([e.feature]);
        });
        control.events.register("outfeature", this, function(e) {
            hover.removeFeatures([e.feature]);
        });
        map.addControl(control);
        control.activate();

        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.Bounds(-140.444336,25.115234,-44.438477,50.580078).getCenterLonLat(), 3);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h1 id="title">WFS GetFeature Example (GeoServer)</h1>
<div id="tags">WFS, GetFeature</div>
<p id="shortdesc">Shows how to use the GetFeature control to select features from a WMS layer.</p>
<div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
<div id="docs">
<p>Click or drag a box to select features, use the Shift key to add
    features to the selection, use the Ctrl key to toggle a feature's
    selected status. Note that this control also has a hover option, which is enabled in this example. This gives you a visual feedback by loading the feature underneath the mouse pointer from the WFS, but causes a lot of GetFeature requests to be issued.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should set up a ProxyHost for getting information from remote server...more information is [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoIsetupaProxyHost)...

```
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All the data I'm using is in computer, so do I need to set up a ProxyHost?
I'm afraid I don't understand what does proxyhost mean?

Comment: i gave this answer to above code you shared. if you work remote server you have to set up a proxy for retrieving data..